# Button in jade with css doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, pug

I am trying to make the Sign In and Register button to work on my page. When the code for the Sign In button is on top, then the Sign In button doesn't work, and when the code for the Register button is on top, then the Register button doesn't work.

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  br
  br
  body
  div(id="banner2")
  div(id="signin")
    form#SignIn(name="sign in", method="get", action="signin")
        button#btnSignIn(type="submit") Sign In
  div(id="register")
    form#Register(name="register", method="get", action="register")
        button#btnRegister(type="submit") Register
```

This is the code from my css file for these buttons:

```
#register{
    position: absolute;
    right: 180px;
    padding: 110px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
#signin{
    position: absolute;
    right: 240px;
    padding: 110px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

With the code above the Sign In button does not work.

Please help me get both buttons to work!

Comment: have you positioned your forms relative (otherwise it looks like your buttons will sit on top of each other)?  Also can you post the rendered html.  Also are you going to have other inputs in your form? if not you could use links instead

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BfECLnH.png this is what it looks like

Comment: might be irrelevant, but what does the "body" after the double br's do? seems a bit fishy to me. also "type" isnt' a valid form attribute afaik.

Comment: I just put the br's to put more space between the text and the banner below.

Comment: I also changed "type" to "name" and still no luck.

Comment: okay looks like you have an element over the top of your button. if you inspect element of the one that is not working I bet you have something there, again please add your rendered html and more styles to replicate the error otherwise we cannot help you and it will be guess work

Comment: How do I get the rendered html? sorry I'm new to this...

Comment: you can use "inspect element" of the browser to see rendered html.. just right click your signin button > choose "Inspect".

Comment: thanks! http://i.imgur.com/RUX8jYO.png this is what the rendered html looks like.

Comment: expand the signin and register div further and see if they are rendering the buttons properly.. just click arrow ">" next to each to expand..

Comment: Your selectors are different in your css to your jade. `#btnSignIn` and `#btnRegister` in your jade, but `#register` and `#signin` in your css

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/afDDpBs.png this is the expanded version.
after i took that screeenshot i tried changing the #SignIn and #Register and now it looks like this http://i.imgur.com/SzMIIDU.png but both buttons do work. I would like to make the buttons look as they did before though.

Comment: Even when I try to change the size of the buttons in my jade file they stay those large squares.

Comment: can you post the updated code after the buttons were working properly..

Comment: I updated the css file to look like this http://i.imgur.com/452mDZt.png and the rendered html looks like this http://i.imgur.com/RDIYhuR.png

Comment: i can see too much padding(110px) is the reason they look so big, also try reducing the width..

Comment: buttons `#btnSignIn` and `#btnRegister` not have the same selector in css `#signin` and `#register`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the css, first remove the `padding:110px;` and than change the `right:240px` to `right:300px;` for `#btnSignIn` (Click Run Code Snippet)-

```css
#btnRegister{
    position: absolute;
    right: 180px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
#btnSignIn{
    position: absolute;
    right: 300px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnSignIn">Sign In</button>
<button id="btnRegister">Register</button>
```